# Wordpress update failing with Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, iis

**Version** - 
WordPress 4.7.12 running Twenty Seventeen theme with Plesk Onyx has Web Windows Hosting Application

**Error**
When I login into Dashboard and select "Update" option for upgrading WordPress installation to 5.1, it loads for some time and then shows an error message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

There's no other text except for this.

**Wha I've tried so far**

1. I attempted to enable logging by adding the following three attributes into the wp-config file, but no debug file gets generated into the wp-content folder. I checked IIS logs, but couldn't see logs file updating.

   define('WP_DEBUG', true);
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
   define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
2. Deactivated all plugins - Problem persists

Please suggest options to fix this or get more details.

Comment: If you're on apache, might be your .htaccess file. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled. What OS is this on? If linux, you can check your `/var/log` directory and do a `tail -f` on your error_log which would be under a directory like apache2 or httpd, etc. Make sure you can run the `index.php` file directly. Try a `phpinfo.php` file with a call to `phpinfo();` and see if that works. Generally this type of thing usually comes down to wordpress config like setting up your database properly.The error would be in your php error log. Try also `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Just noticed you typed IIS. Not much experience here with Windows server, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that's what error logs are for.

- Try to create **.user.ini or php.ini files** in the same directory contains

**error_log = phperrors.log**

(absolute path is preferred)

And, then run your script again and then check for the same file.

Thanks